# C++: enum type as template argument - global scope

Tags: c++, function, templates, enums, global

I've a this situation:

```
template<typename myEnumType>
int foo(const myEnumType & shortest_paths_algorithm)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    myEnumType enum_type_istance;
    int a = foo(enum_type_istance)
}
```

if I declare

```
typedef enum {AAA, BBB} myEnumType;
```

before the function declaration everything is ok. While, if I write the above line before creating enum_type_istance variable, get the error

> no matching function for call to ‘foo(main()::myEnumType&)’
>   candidate is: template int foo(const myEnumType&)

why??? how can I type-define inside the main?
thank you!

Comment: Using local types as template type arguments is a C++11 feature. Make sure your compiler supports it and you're using C++11 mode (if possible). [Code is working, live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/beea71d10a306b08)

Comment: (btw, I know no reason why you shouldn't use just `enum myEnumType {AAA, BBB};` in C++)

Comment: but why if I instead write 'typedef int myEnumType;' then it works also if I write it inside the main()? what's the difference between 'int' and 'enum'?

Comment: `int` is never a local type. Local types are types defined inside a function. `typedef`s are pretty transparent, so it (seems as it) doesn't care if you use a `typedef` or the type referred to.

Answer (score 4):

You are using C++ prior to C++11, which does not allow "local" types to be used in template arguments. This feature has been, luckily, introduced in C++11. As [you can see](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f14842adb1fceffb) it compiles just fine with the `-std=c++11` flag, while [it fails](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45a8f43314a9205) without.